# Object of type 'A' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I've the following get_or_create method.

```
class LocationView(views.APIView):
    def get_or_create(self, request):
        try:
            location = Location.objects.get(country=request.data.get("country"), city=request.data.get("city"))
            print(location)
            return Response(location, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Location.DoesNotExist:
            serializer = LocationSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get(self, request):
        return self.get_or_create(request)

    def post(self, request):
        return self.get_or_create(request)
```

This works fine for creating a new location, 
However if the location exists, I get the following error,

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Location' is not JSON serializable
[16/Mar/2018 10:10:08] "POST /api/v1/bouncer/location/ HTTP/1.1" 500 96971
```

This is my model serializer,

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Location
        fields = ('id', 'country', 'city', 'longitude', 'latitude')
```

What am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you have bypassed all the logic that DRF does for you, so that you never use your serializer; you are passing your Location object directly to the JSON response in the `try` block.

Instead of doing that, you should instantiate your serializer from the model instance object, then pass that serializer data to the response, like you do in the `except` block.

Answer (score -1):

JSON dumps only works with basic types (str, int, float, bool, None). You're trying to dump an object, which is not 'dump-able'. Convert the object to a dictionary, as for example:

```
location_dict = {
    'id': location.id,
    'country': location.country,
    'city': location.city,
    'longitude': location.longitude,
    'latitude': location.latitude
}
return Response(location_dict, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: The point of DRF is exactly that it serializes model instances.